# Emacs global-set-key to C-TAB

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to set a key-binding to Ctrl+TAB in Emacs.  I used the following call:

```
(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "C-TAB") 'my-func)
```

However, whenever I use it, I get a

```
<C-tab> is undefined
```

error message.  Trying to set the binding to "C-tab" results in an error message.

How can I set my binding to C-TAB?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
(global-set-key [C-tab] 'my-func)
```

Answer (score 53):

Unlike others have suggested, it is a good idea to use `kbd` (or `read-kbd-macro` which is basically the same thing) in case you ever want to use the same configuration files in other versions of Emacs; `kbd` works across several versions of Emacs and XEmacs, where the internal representation of key sequences are different.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'my-func)
```

The input format used by `read-kbd-macro` is documented in the docstring of `edmacro-mode`:

> - The special words RET, SPC, TAB, DEL, LFD, ESC, and NUL represent
>     special control characters.  The words must be written in uppercase.
> - A word in angle brackets, e.g., <return>, <down>, or <f1>, represents
>     a function key.  (Note that in the standard configuration, the
>     function key <return> and the control key RET are synonymous.)
>     You can use angle brackets on the words RET, SPC, etc., but they
>     are not required there.

This is written somewhat unfortunately; the TAB referred to in the first bullet point is the ASCII character for TAB, and adding the Control modifier does something nonsensical to it. When you press Control-Tab, Emacs sees it (via your windowing system; it will not work in a text terminal) as `<tab>` with a Control modifier, which you can represent as `C-<tab>` or `<C-tab>`.

Comment: Is there a workaround for `<C-tab>` in emacs in a text terminal? I asked on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/81688/problem-with-ctrl-tab-keybinding-in-emacs-in-gnome-terminal

Comment: kbd is a macro documented at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html and is used to convert the keybinding format used in Emacs documentation to values understood by functions such as global-set-key.

Comment: Why is it "<C-tab>" instead of "C-<tab>"?

Answer (score 11):

It's because you are using `read-kbd-macro` incorrectly.  When you see what is bound to a key:

```
C-h k C-TAB
```

Emacs tells you:

```
<C-tab> is undefined.
```

You need to include the <> in your invocation of `read-kbd-macro`.

```
(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "<C-tab>") 'my-func)
```

And, I don't know how to generate `<C-TAB>`, but it's not the same as `<C-tab>`.

```
(equal (kbd "<C-TAB>") (kbd "<C-tab>"))
->
nil
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that you can also call `global-set-key` interactively. You can then see the correct binding command with `repeat-complex-command` (see also [KeybindingGuide](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeybindingGuide)):

1. `M-x: global-set-key`
2. Type the key combination you want
3. Use `C-x ESC ESC` (`repeat-complex-command`) to see the apropiate command. In your case I get:

   ```
   (global-set-key (quote [C-tab]) (quote my-func))
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `read-kbd-macro`, try using the more plain syntax?

```
;(global-set-key [(control tab)] 'my-func)
```

Perhaps the plainer syntax will make a difference?

More on [read-kbd-macro](http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/21.5/html/xemacs-faq_8.html#SEC281) and [global-set-key](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html).

Comment: The big advantage of using `(kbd)` is that you can use the same syntax that Emacs returns when you call `describe-key`, which makes it completely trivial to deal with (as demonstrated nicely by Trey's answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the gnu emacs lisp reference manual, section 21.1 "Key Sequences", they reference using \t to represent the tab key.

Using the syntax shown in the Lisp reference manual,  I would use the following command:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-\t") 'my-func)`