# How can I remap TAB in Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp

This feels like it should be simple but it's been driving me crazy.  I've got a function `indent-or-expand` that I'd like to remap to <kbd>tab</kbd> but I simply can't get it to work (Emacs v24, OS X).  The only help I've been able to get from Emacs itself is:

> error "To bind the key TAB, use \"\\t\", not [TAB]"

Doing `(global-set-key [\"\\t\"] 'indent-or-expand)` binds the function to `<"\t">` apparently (whatever that is), and every combination I've tried of <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>, and <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> has failed.

I DID manage to bind the function to <kbd>t</kbd>, though...

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916797/emacs-global-set-key-to-c-tab

Comment: @abo-abo Saw.  `C-tab` != `tab`

Comment: I meant that most of the answers there will work for your question. It's just a matter of substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what others have told you:

1. The Emacs error message you cite told you to use "\t", and if you use that you should be OK:

   (global-set-key "\t" 'indent-or-expand)
2. Be aware also that `TAB` is one thing and `<tab>` might be another thing.  IOW, it depends what code your physical keyboard `Tab` key actually sends to Emacs.  `TAB` is the tab character, and it i the same as ACSCII control character `C-i`, that is, `Control` + `i`, which has decimal integer value 9.  `<tab>` is (in Emacs) a pseudo function key.  (Most likely `TAB` is what you want.  Use `C-h k` to see what your physical `Tab` key does.)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Why did Emacs use over-extensive escaping?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by over-extensive escaping. Backslashes are special chars, introducing syntax like `\n` for newline, `\t` for tab etc. To escape a backslash in an ambiguous context, so it is taken literally, you double it. In a Lisp string, you further need to double such backslashes. See `(elisp) Basic Char Syntax`, `(elisp) Syntax for Strings` and `(elisp) Regexp Special`. From the last one: the read syntax for a regular expression matching \ is "\\\\".

Answer (score 2):

Use the `kbd` function, i.e.:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") ...)
```